# What's a word that can be used to describe an infinite loop or a recurring event?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Example:

> The GIFs on the internet are ***stuck in an infinite loop***.

I'm trying to find a word that describes an event that continues on forever and is recurring.

Comment: "Infinite loop", "tight loop", "recursion".

Comment: It repeats *ad infinitum* or *ad nauseum*.  // Please give us a sample sentence and the context.

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard *'perpetual* loop'. (It conjures thoughts of eternal repetition.)

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard that.  (Though I've easily encountered thousands of "infinite" loops in my career.)

Comment: It has nothing to do with modern tech jargon, and everything to do with the fact that when I went to college *computer* meant *univac*. I believe it's an ancient *mechanical* term.

Comment: Well, in engineering school I used a Univac remotely (it was in Tennessee, IIRC), using a batch terminal based on a PDP-8.

Comment: See, I stayed on the opposite end of the campus.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no such a word exists, because the simplest form used in programming languages to describe this is "loop".